# How to find the resource name from exception

Tags: android, android-layout

While running an application, I got the following exception.

```
android.content.res.Resources$ResourcesNotFoundException: Resource ID # 0X7F03000a
```

The exception trace points to the method- setContentView(R.layout.main)
But main.xml is present in the application directory.

How can I identify the resource name from the resource ID?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when something like that happens, it's because the build screwed up somehow so the generated R class doesn't have it.

In Eclipse, go to `Project->Clean...` and select your project.  It will build your application from scratch.

Also, make sure that the layout `main.xml` is in the `res/layout` folder.  It must be in that folder for Eclipse to auto-generate properly.

Comment: There you are! I got it working. I cleaned and did a build. Thanks a lot

Comment: It's a handy thing to know because it happens quite often for some reason.

Comment: Yeah true! But I was looking for some other bugs and just beating round the bushes...

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the R class, it is a class generated automatically. If you are using eclipse, you can find it in the "gen" folder.